# Knockout JS filter functionality in index.cshtml file

Tags: dynamic, knockout.js, grid

I'm trying to write a dynamic code to use knockout across pages. For that I've a common.js file which has all the required functionality. But for filter functionality as it is different per page, I'm writing it in index.cshtml file. The code what I've written for filtering, if I put it in common.js, it works fine but it doesn't filter the data if I put it in index.cshtml file. I've created a JSFiddle for it, but for some reason it's not showing correctly. The link for the same is http://jsfiddle.net/maulikk2000/FGkKx/ . So, my question is what I'm doing wrong here. I'm putting just JS code here as index.cshtml code gets bit unreadable. Commented line at the bottom of index.cshtml in jsfiddle ( $.getJSON) is my real code.

```
function CreateGrid(gridId, itemObject, pageSize, initializeFilterByItems, dataItems) {

    var self = this;

    self.gridId = gridId;


    self.itemObjectArray = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(dataItems, function (data) {
        return new itemObject(data);

    }));

    self.pageSize = ko.observable(pageSize);
    self.pageIndex = ko.observable(1);
    self.prevPageIndex = ko.observable(1);

    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.itemForEditing = ko.observable();



    initializeFilterByItems(self.itemObjectArray);


    self.stringStartsWith = function (item, startsWith) {

        item = item || "";

        if (startsWith.length > item.length) return false;
        return item.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;

    };

    self.templateToUse = function (item) {

        var item1 = self.selectedItem();

        var template = item === item1 ? 'editTmpl' : 'itemsTmpl';
        return template;

    };

    self.pagedList = ko.computed(function () {

        var size = self.pageSize();
        var start = (self.pageIndex() - 1) * size;

        var itemsToReturn = this.filteredItems ? this.filteredItems : self.itemObjectArray;

        //return self.filteredItems.slice(start, start + size);
        return itemsToReturn.slice(start, start + size);

    });

    self.maxPageIndex = ko.computed(function () {
        return Math.ceil(self.itemObjectArray().length / self.pageSize());

    });

    self.totalItems = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.itemObjectArray().length;
    });

    self.previousPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() > 1) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
            self.prevPageIndex(self.pageIndex());
        }
    };

    self.nextPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() <= self.maxPageIndex()) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
            self.prevPageIndex(self.pageIndex());
        }
    };

    self.firstPage = function () {
        self.pageIndex(1);
        self.prevPageIndex(1);
    };

    self.lastPage = function () {
        self.pageIndex(self.maxPageIndex());
        self.prevPageIndex(self.maxPageIndex());
    };

    self.pageIndex.subscribe(function (item) {

        if (item) {

            var jumpToPage = parseInt(item);

            if (jumpToPage <= self.maxPageIndex()) {
                self.pageIndex(jumpToPage);
                self.prevPageIndex(jumpToPage);
            } else {

                self.pageIndex(self.prevPageIndex());

            }
        }

    });

    self.allPages = ko.computed(function () {

        var pages = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= self.maxPageIndex(); i++) {
            pages.push({
                pageNumber: (i + 1)
            });
        }
        return pages;
    });

    self.moveToPage = function (index) {
        self.pageIndex(index);
    };

    self.selectItem = function (item) {
        self.selectedItem(item);
        self.itemForEditing(new itemObject(ko.toJS(item)));

    };

    self.acceptItem = function (item) {

        var validationError = ko.validation.group(item);
        var vlength = validationError().length;

        if (vlength == 0) {

            var selected = self.selectedItem(),
                edited = self.itemForEditing();

            var currentdate = new Date();
            var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + currentdate.getDate() + " " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds() + "." + currentdate.getMilliseconds();


            item.Date_Last_Updated(datetime);
            var id = selected.ContractorServiceId();

            ajaxUpdate(updateItemUrl + id, ko.toJSON(item), function () {

               edited.update(selected);

                self.selectedItem(null);
                self.itemForEditing(null);
            },

            function (errorText) {
                alert(errorText);
                selected.update(edited);
            });

        } else {

        }
    };

    self.revertItem = function (item) {
        var selected = self.selectedItem(),
            edited = ko.toJS(self.itemForEditing());
        selected.update(edited);

        self.selectedItem(null);
        self.itemForEditing(null);
    };

    self.remove = function (item) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + " '" + item.ContractorServiceDescription() + "'??")) {

            var itemId = item.ContractorServiceId();

            ajaxDelete(deleteItemUrl + itemId, function () {
                self.itemObjectArray.remove(item);
            },

            function (errorMessage) {
                alert(errorMessage);
            });

        }

    };

    self.getAll = function () {

        self.itemObjectArray.removeAll();

        $.getJSON(readItemUrl, function (services) {

            $.each(services, function (index, service) {
                self.itemObjectArray.push(new itemObject(service));
           });

        });
    };

    self.add = function () {

        var data = {};
        data.ContractorServiceId = "enter new id here";
        data.ContractorServiceDescription = "enter new description here";
        var newItem = new itemObject(data);

        self.selectedItem(newItem);

        $("#contractorServiceDialog").dialog({

            width: 420,
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Save',
                    "class": 'commonButtonStyle',
                    "autofocus": this,
                click: function () {
                    var validationError = ko.validation.group(self.selectedItem());
                    var vlength = validationError().length;

                    if (vlength != 0) {

                    } else {

                        $(this).dialog("close");

                        var item = self.selectedItem();

                        ajaxAdd(addItemUrl, ko.toJSON(item), function () {
                            self.getAll();
                        },

                        function (errorText) {
                            alert(errorText);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, {
                text: "Cancel",
                    "class": 'commonButtonStyle',
                click: function () {
                    self.itemObjectArray.remove(newItem); // We need to remove this otherwise it'll appear on the last page...
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]


        });


    };

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to go through. It would help if you'd narrow down the issue, create an [sscce](http://sscce.org), and tell us what you've tried to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Jeroen,      thanks for the reply.. I can understand that there is a lot of code to go through, but my main purpose is to give a better understanding. My main problem is with model.filteredItems call. It starts at line number 160 in HTML code on the fiddle link above. I want to filter the list based on the values typed in Id and Description fields. Currently my grid is bound to self.PagedList method on line 43 in javascript section. what I'm trying to do is to create a common code for most of the functionality, but filter functionality is page specific. Hope it helps, Maulik

Comment: Hi, I've removed a lot of unnecessary code for this problem on JSFiddle link. It is much more clearner now and easy to understand.

Comment: Good deal! However, I think it didn't work, because there's still a few 100 sloc in the fiddle and question. (Note that you can always [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16538135/edit) to improve it.)